# Not quite cake material

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm not a mammal, no flier-by-night,
>   (though I too have been known to
>   give you a fright).
>
> And you might just stutter when finding my name
>    (but I'll give you
>   energy to try again).
>
> My end is quite short - and it's part of a key.
>   (Just please use the
>   right way to dispose of me!)

And one more stanza, just for fun:

> Still stuck? Here, try this: you can buy me with money,
>  or sometimes with Na, if you're being funny.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You're a Battery. The three parts together reference a nocturnal mammal (BAT), a stuttering syllable (TER), and part of the word key (Y). We also have the extra clues about energy and correct disposal.
>  EDIT: My explanation was lacking a response to the second line, but I think the wordplay is that giving someone a "fright" is like giving them a "shock", which batteries can do since they're electric.

Comment: Also, it's not quite cake material, i.e. batter.

Comment: Yep, you got it! Thanks for puzzling it out (and to @phenomist for getting the title)!